# How to make VSCode pylance's auto import works like PyCharm's

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I used to develop python using PyCharm, but now I want to use VScode as my IDE for my python development because of the remote container. But I get problem when trying to import method/class from existing python library.

In the example I want to import `AbstractBaseUser` class from `django.contrib.auth.base_user`, but the IDE doesn't show the correct auto completion for importing the class(it doesn't even recognize the `AbstractBaseUser` when I press `ctrl + space`, it says "no suggestions"). But when I import it manually, it exists.

How do I make pylance's auto import works like the one in PyCharm?

[image]